# Stata on batch mode and log file

Tags: batch-file, logging, stata

Say I have the following folder structure.

`/foo
     /bar1
         code.do
     /bar2`

I want to run Stata on batch mode and have the log file generated inside /foo/bar2. What exact batch code should I run?

I'll give you examples that I tried and that didn't work. Right now the log file is being created as stata.log inside /foo. Also, I would like to run Stata on batch mode with -b, and not seeing the whole output on my GUI.

`stata-se < "/foo/bar1/code.do" > "/foo/bar2"`

`stata-se "/foo/bar1/code.do" "/foo/bar2"`

`stata-se do "/foo/bar1/code.do" "/foo/bar2"`

`stata-se -b do "/foo/bar1/code.do" "/foo/bar2"`

Answer (score 2):

Both methods work for me. Below my exact terminal commands after creating your example directories:

### Method 1

```
$ stata <  /home/roberto/Desktop/foo/bar1/code.do > /home/roberto/Desktop/foo/bar2/code.log
```

### Method 2

```
$ cd /home/roberto/Desktop/foo/bar2
$ stata -b /home/roberto/Desktop/foo/bar1/code.do
```

Notice that with Method 2, Stata will write the log file to the current directory. Just change it before running Stata.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to specify your log file inside of your do-file

```
log using /home/roberto/Desktop/foo/bar2/code.log, replace
```

Then you can run the file from batch mode without worrying about current directory